# How Transformations are calculated lazily in LiveData?

Tags: android

According to Doc

> The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is observing the returned LiveData object.Because the transformations are calculated lazily, lifecycle-related behavior is implicitly passed down without requiring additional explicit calls or dependencies.

But we are not passing any LifeCycleOwner to switchmap or map methods unlike observe method in LiveData.Then how Transformations aren't calculated?

Comment: see `MediatorLiveData` sources - it will explain everything

Comment: I am looking at the source and am trying to figure out how hasActiveObservers() method works. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: addSource method will observe forever if it has active observer but am not getting how hasActiveObservers() works. @pskink

Comment: see `LiveData.java` then

Comment: @pskink No actually, in LiveData there are more Unknown classes I don't know of, so I couldn't get a clear picture of it. Maybe I will get it over time.